# Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'

Tags: jboss7.x, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to implemenmt Spring security with Oauth2 for Rest API.
well I have successfully implemented this. and everything was working fine.
but then I put 'jboss-deployement-structure.xml' in WEB-INF folder

and suddenly Im getting this Exception: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate Filter registration for 'springSecurityFilterChain'.

I have done some debugging and found out that 'onStartup()' method of 'AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer' is getting executed twice (after I added 'jboss-deployement-structure.xml')

so this is attempting to add same filter twice. and hence the exception

but I dont know why this is happening and how to solve this.
please help

My web.xml:

```
<display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value> /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

My mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.clickawaiter" />
<bean id="customerPortalController"
    class="com.clickawaiter.customerportal.controller.CustomerPortalController">
    <property name="merchantServiceImpl" ref="merchantServiceImpl"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="merchantServiceImpl"
    class="com.clickawaiter.customerportal.serviceimpl.MerchantServiceImpl"></bean>

<bean id="userService" class="com.clickawaiter.security.UserService">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/CAW_DS" /> <!-- value="java:CAW_DS" -->
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

My WEbAPplicationInitializer:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer{

}
```

Comment: Your wrote: *and everything was working fine.* Which web server is working fine?

Comment: No, the working one. You wrote that it is not working with JBoss EAP 7.